# Getting "not a single-group group function"

Tags: oracle

Below is the query that I am running, but I am getting not a single-group group function error? Please explain why is this error coming and a possible solution to this.

```
SELECT 1                          AS "Contract",
  COUNT(DISTINCT(cmv.mdl_ver_id)) AS "Number Of Scenarios",
  COUNT(DISTINCT(cmvs.site_id))   AS "Number Of Sites",
  CASE
    WHEN cmve.driver_equip_id is null
    THEN COUNT(distinct(cmve.equip_mdl_id))
  END                             AS "Number of Driven",
  CASE
    WHEN cmve.driver_equip_id is not null
    THEN COUNT(distinct(cmve.equip_mdl_id))
  END                             AS "Number of Driver" 
 FROM cost_contract_mdl ccm,
  cost_model_ver cmv,
  cost_mdl_ver_site cmvs,
  cost_mdl_ver_equip cmve
WHERE ccm.mdl_id   =cmv.mdl_id
AND cmv.mdl_ver_id =cmvs.mdl_ver_id
AND cmv.mdl_ver_id =4281021;
```

Comment: FYI that your query contains a cross join to cmve. You might already be aware but I just wanted to bring it to your attention in case you weren't. Some folks prefer ANSI style joins. Those make cross joins much more obvious.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion. I have just started working on DB and will appreciate more suggestions. 
Is there any performance improvement in Joins than the conventional way?

Comment: @JoeObbish Forgot to tag you.

Comment: I don't know of a performance benefit. It's more of a style issue and a way to protect you against typos. Here's an article around SQL Server but the same principles apply for Oracle: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `GROUP BY`, then you can only use constant, and aggregate functions is the SELECT clause.

This is wrong:
CASE
    WHEN **cmve.driver_equip_id** is null
    THEN COUNT(distinct(cmve.equip_mdl_id))
  END

CASE
    WHEN **cmve.driver_equip_id** is not null
    THEN COUNT(distinct(cmve.equip_mdl_id))
  END

---

`count (distinct case ... end)` is probably what you need.

```
SELECT 1                          AS "Contract",
  COUNT(DISTINCT cmv.mdl_ver_id) AS "Number Of Scenarios",
  COUNT(DISTINCT cmvs.site_id)   AS "Number Of Sites",
  count (distinct CASE
    WHEN cmve.driver_equip_id is null
    THEN cmve.equip_mdl_id
  END)                             AS "Number of Driven",
  count (distinct CASE
    WHEN cmve.driver_equip_id is not null
    THEN cmve.equip_mdl_id
  END)                             AS "Number of Driver" 
 FROM cost_contract_mdl ccm,
  cost_model_ver cmv,
  cost_mdl_ver_site cmvs,
  cost_mdl_ver_equip cmve
WHERE ccm.mdl_id   =cmv.mdl_id
AND cmv.mdl_ver_id =cmvs.mdl_ver_id
AND cmv.mdl_ver_id =4281021;
```

P.s.

`DISTINCT` is not a function, it is a keyword, which makes the parentheses meaningless.

Instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT(x))`
It should be `COUNT(DISTINCT x)`

Comment: See updated answer